# How to set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i'm going to install node-fprint package on lubuntu 20.04

Then the terminal shows me this type of "error"

Package libfprint was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libfprint.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libfprint' found

I tried to do everything and it doesn't work, someone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same type of error

```
npm ERR! Package pixman-1 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
npm ERR! Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pixman-1.pc'
npm ERR! to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
npm ERR! No package 'pixman-1' found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
```